# iOS Swift: Retrieve transaction list from Apple Wallet

Tags: transactions, applepay, wallet

I'm looking for the possibility to retrieve all the transactions made with ApplePay that are listed in the Wallet.

I can't find any reference in the Apple Guides, do you know if a third app can access with the user permission to the ApplePay payments list?

Comment: Accessing any pass content is restricted to the card issuer.  Payment card APIs are restricted and not publicly available.